# Google Oauth2.0 No sytem CA bundle could be found

Tags: php, oauth, guzzle, google-authentication

Here is my code

```
require_once 'core_php/google-api-php-client-2.0.2_PHP54/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile
($_SERVER['SR_WEB_CPANEL_PATH'].'asserts/php/client_secret.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://..../googleapi/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {

    $client->setHttpClient(new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify'=>'C:/Windows/System32/curl-ca-bundle.crt']));

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = '/googleapi/index.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Then it has a Fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message ' No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations. PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates, you will need to supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to the 'verify' request option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. Once you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify' request option. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more information.

I am using PHP 5.4. 
I tried to download the CA bundle from the link that the error message provided.
And added two lines in php.ini

```
openssl.cafile = 'C:/Windows/System32/curl-ca-bundle.crt'
curl.cainfo = 'C:/Windows/System32/cacert.pem'
```

And it still does not work.

Can anybody help? Thank you so much.

Comment: Is your `curl.cainfo...` entry under a `[curl]` section ?

Comment: Yes. I only uncomment the 
curl.cainfo = 'C:/Windows/System32/cacert.pem'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know what happens. I installed PHP 5.6 finally.